# How to separate input form for each entry in a single template

Tags: html, django, forms, list, view

I have a list of entries which are displayed in a webpage. Each entry has the same input form. But my problem arises when data is put into the input form, it appears on every single one of them. How do I change this.

Each input form is treated as a single cloned entity distributed over many entries.

**views.py**

> def topic(request, topic_id, type): #

```
topic = Topic.objects.get(id = topic_id, type = 't_topic')


entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')

images = Image.objects.filter(imgtopic__in = entries)


ArticleFormSet = formset_factory(CheckAnswer, extra = 2)


if request.method == 'POST':

    formset = ArticleFormSet(request.POST) 

    if form.is_valid():

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:index'))
else:

    formset = ArticleFormSet() 




context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries, 'images': images, 'formset': formset}
return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)
```

**topic.html template**

> {%load staticfiles %}
>   {% block content %}

{% for entry in entries(n) %}

```
<div class = 'secondary-container'> 

    <li>


    <div class = 'date'>
        <p >{{ entry.date_added|date:'M d, Y H:i'}}</p>
    </div>




        {%include 'learning_logs/view_files.html'%}


    <div class = 'video-container'>
        {%include 'learning_logs/video.html' %}
    </div>

    <div class = 'entry-text'>
        <p>{{ entry.text|linebreaks }}</p>
        <p>$ {{entry.price_set.get.ptext}}</p>
    </div>

    </li>

    <li> 


        <p> Enter Answer: </p>

        <form action = "{%url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id topic.type%}" method = 'post'>

            {{formset.management_form}}
            <table> 
                {% for form in formset%}
                        {{form.as_p}}
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <button name = "submit">Submit answer</button>


                {% endfor %}
            </table>



        </form>





</div>
```

**forms.py**

> class CheckAnswer(forms.Form):

```
your_answer = forms.CharField(label = "Enter Your Key", max_length = 100)

def clean(self):

    cleaned_data=super(CheckAnswer, self).clean() 
    your_answer = cleaned_data.get("your_answer")

    try: 

        p = Keys.objects.get(key = your_answer)
    except Keys.DoesNotExist: 

        raise forms.ValidationError("Incorrect code.")
```

My new problem is that I can't separate the forms into the different lists. Since extra = 2, I get 2 instances of forms on the same entry list.

I tried using the {%for form in formset%} command in the topic.html template to give each entry a form, but I get an of ['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with'] when I click submit.

[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCTli.jpg)

Comment: You need to look at [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/formsets/).

Comment: Thank you for help, but I still run onto the problem where form is displayed twice (if extra = 2) within same entry list. How do I make it so that each form is displayed on a different entry list? Please have look at my updated code

Comment: With a formset, the entire group of inputs are all submitted via the same form, so you don't need to iterate through the entries. You just [iterate through the formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/formsets/#manually-rendered-can-delete-and-can-order) and render each individual form piece, as well as the management form. Then, in your view you can handle the saving / updating of the individual entries, if they have been altered.

Comment: I seem to be stuck. We have a problem with a nested loop here. I went through the jinja documentation and searched the internet for while, but I can't find the right answer. All of the forms in the formset are displayed all at once in the same entry list.  I want 1 form to be displayed per entry. What is the best of doing this? Please have a look at my updated codes.

Comment: Your formset would be all submitted in the same <form>. However I am looking a bit more in depth, and I am not clear how you are associating your CheckAnswer form to the Entry object on the page. How do you know that the `key` in the checkanswer is correct for the given model?

Comment: I have a Keys Model with a 'key' field, any data that is put into the forms is compared with the data within the Keys model through the CheckAnswer.  My problem arises because the formset is looped/extracted within each entry. For instance, If I have 5 entries, I want each entry to have one and only one CheckAnswer form (if extra =>5). In my current situation, all of the forms are looped through and are dumped in the same entry because the formset is within the entry in the template.